# How to let only certain people use a command in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command that is this:

```
@client.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('~superknot'):
        if message.author == "random id here":
            yield from client.say('are you sure?')
            msg = yield from client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='yes')
            yield from client.say("---")
```

so that only one person can do this command, but, it isn't working, how come?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to simply change `message.author` to `message.author.id`.
But what I recommend is to use [checks.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/rewrite/cogs/utils/checks.py) for async, and [discord.ext.commands.checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#checks) for rewrite. both examples are using the commands extension.

Comment: it says a string has no attributes called author

Comment: update the question so i can see the new code you're using

Answer (score 0):

You currently have it to check if the entire message.author value is equal to only one part of itself. To fix this, replace `message.author` to `message.author.id`